# Duplex WCF net.tcp service disposed object exception for my client

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server, duplex, duplex-channel

I implemented a client-server application for chatting with WCF. And i have a callback for broadcasting. It was working properly until i changed some functions. I was using my dataset fix data. It was initialized on my server and was used. I implemented an XML parser mechanism and then i'm getting an error like that:

> Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext'.

I'm using my service like that:

```
System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext context = new System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext(this.cb);
this._client = new WCFDevComServiceClient(context);
```

and then i'm openning this._client just one time and i'm using this object for my each call. (I don't close this object anytime.)

If i open before each call and then close it, then it's working. But in this case my callback function doesn't work. And i can't broadcast. So I can't close my client object.

Do you have any further information about this error? Or any fix suggestion?

My Service Codes:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class WCFDevComService : IWCFDevComService
{
    private const string deviceXmlPath = @"D:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WCFBroadcastorService\WCFDeviceCom\WCFDeviceCom_Service\bin\Devices.xml";
    private const string userXmlPath = @"D:\MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WCFBroadcastorService\WCFDeviceCom\WCFDeviceCom_Service\bin\Users.xml";
    private DbOperations.DbOperations dbOperator = new DbOperations.DbOperations();
    private static List<User> UserCollection = new List<User>(); 
    private static Dictionary<string, IWCFDevComServiceBroadcastorCallback> clients = new Dictionary<string, IWCFDevComServiceBroadcastorCallback>();
    private static object locker = new object(); 
    private List<Device> deviceCollection = new List<Device>();

    public bool LoginToServer(string clientName)
    {
        bool retVal = false;

        if (clientName != "")
        { 

            retVal = CheckUserName(clientName);
            if (true == retVal)
            {
                try
                {
                    IWCFDevComServiceBroadcastorCallback callback =
                        OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IWCFDevComServiceBroadcastorCallback>();

                    if (clients.Keys.Contains(clientName))
                        clients.Remove(clientName);
                    clients.Add(clientName, callback);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    private bool CheckUserName(string clientName)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            UserCollection = dbOperator.QueryForGetAllUsers(userXmlPath);

            foreach (var user in UserCollection)
            {
                if (user.m_userName.Contains(clientName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    public List<Device> GetAllDevicesInformation()
    {
        try
        {
            return GetInformationFromDeviceXML();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
            return null;
        }

    }

    private List<Device> GetInformationFromDeviceXML()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                deviceCollection = dbOperator.QueryForGetAllDevices(deviceXmlPath);
            }

            return deviceCollection;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
            return null;
        }

    }

    public int GetNumberOfDevices()
    {
        try
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                //todo: GetNumberOfDevicesFromXML 
                return dbOperator.QueryForGetDeviceCount(deviceXmlPath);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
            return 0;
        }

    }

    public Device GetDeviceInformation(int index)
    {
        List<Device> deviceCollection = GetInformationFromDeviceXML();

        return deviceCollection[index];
    }

    public int BlockedDevice(int index, User user)
    {
        try
        {
            if (index < 0 && user == null)
                return -1; //fail

            lock (locker)
            {
                if (deviceCollection[index].m_state.m_state != States.Free)
                    return 1; // isn't free for blocking
                DeviceState tmpState = new DeviceState();
                tmpState.m_state = States.Locked;
                tmpState.m_lockedUser = user;
                deviceCollection[index].m_state = tmpState;
                //todo: UpdateXML
                dbOperator.QueryForUpdateDeviceStateById(deviceXmlPath, index + 1, tmpState);
                //deviceCollection = GetInformationFromDeviceXML();
                NotifyOtherClients(index, user);
                return 0; //success
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
            return -1;

        }


    }

    public int FreeDevice(int index, User user)
    {
        try
        {
            if (index < 0 && user == null)
                return -1; //fail

            lock (locker)
            {
                if (deviceCollection[index].m_state.m_state != States.Locked)
                    return 1; // isn't locked to free

                if (deviceCollection[index].m_state.m_lockedUser.m_userName != user.m_userName && user.m_userPermission != Permission.ADMIN)
                    return 2; // isn't right person
                DeviceState tmpState = new DeviceState();
                tmpState.m_state = States.Free;
                tmpState.m_lockedUser = null;
                deviceCollection[index].m_state = tmpState;
                //todo: UpdateXML
                dbOperator.QueryForUpdateDeviceStateById(deviceXmlPath, index + 1, tmpState);
                //deviceCollection = GetInformationFromDeviceXML();
                NotifyOtherClients(index, user);
                return 0; //success
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
            return -1;
        }


    }

    public Permission GetPermission(string userName)
    {
        lock (locker)
        {
            foreach (var user in UserCollection)
            {
                if (user.m_userName == userName)
                    return user.m_userPermission;
            }

            return Permission.USER;
        }
    }


    private void NotifyOtherClients(int index, User user)
    {
        try
        {
            var inactiveClients = new List<string>();
            EventDataType eventData = new EventDataType();
            eventData.ClientName = user.m_userName;
            eventData.Index = index;
            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                if (client.Key != eventData.ClientName)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        client.Value.BroadcastToClient(eventData);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        inactiveClients.Add(client.Key);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (inactiveClients.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var client in inactiveClients)
                {
                    clients.Remove(client);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show  some `WCFDevComServiceClient` code? And what's `this.cb`?

Comment: `this.cb` is the object implementing the the _callback_ interface.

Comment: @Artyom, i added my WCFDevComServiceClient codes. But this codes was generated with svsutil.exe. Also this.cb is the object of my callback interface.

Comment: Post your actual service implementation rather than boilerplate code generated by svcutil.

Comment: @jstreet i added. And if you are available we can make a live meeting.

Comment: There are too many dependencies.... Read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)